# how to change the result of Time.now?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the results of `Time.now` with the results `Time.zone.now`

```
Time.now #=> 2015-05-08 14:06:07 +0700
Time.zone.now #=> Fri, 08 May 2015 02:07:09 CDT -05:00
```

should be

```
Time.now #=> Fri, 08 May 2015 02:07:09 CDT -05:00
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use `Time.current` instead of `Time.now`

Comment: can i still use `Time.now` ?

Comment: of course, `Time.now` is the built-in Ruby method, `Time.current` is a Rails addition

Comment: Time.now returns system time and ignores your configured time zone.
If you really want to use only Time.now instead of Time.current, you should to set up correct time for your whole operation system.

Comment: ohh, i see.. means I have to use `Time.current` or `Time.zone.now` to get the results I want .. because I think to change of time in each operating system on the application it's more difficult.

Comment: Thank you already want to answer my question